# Local variables inside map variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, local-variables

I am trying to use a map variable(which has 2 lambda names). Also, I want to pass a local variable inside the key values, as shown in the example below.However, I get an error as variable not allowed here. Any suggestions/advice?

**variables.tf:**

```
variable "lambdas" {
type = map(string)
default = {
"lambda1_name-${local.global_suffix}"   = "lambda_function1",
"lambda2_name-${local.global_suffix}" = "lambda_function2"
}
}

locals{
global_suffix   = "${var.env}-${var.project}${var.branch_hash}"
}
```

**main.tf:**

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "main" {
for_each         = var.lambdas
function_name    = each.key
handler          = "${each.value}.${var.handler}"
filename         = "${path.module}/modules/lambda-main/${each.value}.zip"
source_code_hash = data.archive_file.init[each.key].output_base64sha256
role             = module.lambda_iam_role.arn
runtime          = "python3.6"
memory_size      = "2048"
timeout          = "900"
tags             = local.tags
description      = "${var.project} Lambda Function"
}
```

I am trying to use one lambda resource block  to create 2 lambda functions(hence using the map variable)

Comment: Ok, but what's wrong with your code? Any errors?

Comment: I don't see the exact, complete error message anywhere in your post. Please [edit] to provide it. It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable default values **can't by dynamic**. They must be static values. Thus, instead of having `var.lambdas`, in your case it would be better to use `locals`:

```
variable "lambdas" {
  type = map(string)
    default = {
    "lambda1_name" = "lambda_function1",
    "lambda2_name" = "lambda_function2"
  }
}

locals {
  lambdas = {for key, value in var.lambdas: "${key}-${local.global_suffix}" => value}
}
```

Them you would:'

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "main" {
    for_each         = local.lambdas
    ....
}
```